# jSignature on Android device using Chrome doesn't work when zoomed

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, jsignature

When I use Chrome on any mobile device the signature will only work if the page is displayed in default zoom. If I zoom in on the signature area it won't render correctly. It looks like the x and y coordinates are offset and the signature is drawn outside the visible area.

This issue can be reproduced on the jSignature demo site:
http://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/demo/

Example devide: Samsung Galaxy S5 using Chrome version 46.0.2490.76

I have also tested on a Lenovo tablet with the same result in Chrome.

I'm wondering if anyone has a workaround/fix for this?

Thanks,

Per